# Uses of ICs outputing 1 value only

Tags: digital-logic, integrated-circuit

There are some integrated circuits which output only digital value 0 or 1 regardless of the input for example:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fFmaDR.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

This outputs 1 regardless of the input. Where do we use them?

Comment: What IC is this supposed to be? Give some examples.

Comment: "We" don't. Have you ever seen such a circuit in a real application?

Comment: My bad sorry.....

Comment: It you consider the powersupply of the logic gate another input then you have two inputs and one output.  The source and sink of the input and output are very unmatched but perhaps that is what the designer wanted for some reason.  If you have a coin cell at the bottom and a RTC clock chip at the top it might even work as an automatic power fail transfer switch, maybe.

Answer (score 3):

You can only understand such circuits if you know the inner schematic of the inverter block used. It uses the inverter as a comparator and inverting amplifier.

For example, if this was a single-stage CMOS inverter (as found e.g. in the CD4007 chip), the resulting circuit would be as follows:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fRq0wY.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

The diode renders the lower MOSFET ineffective. It cannot pull the output to ground any more. But the upper MOSFET can still connect Vdd to the output, if the input is below 0.5·Vdd (this is a characteristic of CMOS inverters). So, the function is as follows:

- input below 0.5·Vdd: output at Vdd with high-current capacity
- input above 0.5·Vdd: output at input voltage with low current capacity (through the resistor)

The resistor must be large enough so the input can be easily driven low by the feeding circuit to the left. If it isn't, this circuit will oscillate at a few MHz.

This circuit may be used for a pullup of variable strength, for example.

Answer (score 0):

> This outputs 1 regardless of the input.

Incorrect.
If the output of the inverter is a 1, the input of the inverter will **also** see a 1, because there is no current running through R1, and the output becomes a 0.

If the output is 0 the diode is ideally reversed biased and  the input is floating and can become anything.

The circuit will quite likely oscillate as it is not stable.

Comment: Yes my bad sorry 4 ur time ty <3

Comment: delete question

Comment: @MrsChemistry No problem.